# NodeJS - Поиск файла циклом

Tags: javascript, node.js

Возникла проблема, которой в других языках просто не существует, либо я попросту не умею гуглить (да и знания js практически нулевые).

Ближе к проблеме - мне необходимо проверить наличие папки и файла в ней, после получить его данные для чтения.

Существует ли способ циклом (либо другим возможным способом) найти данный файл при условии, что название папки неизвестно?

Её название не статично и может меняться в зависимости от ситуации.

На PHP я бы мог зайти в папку (которая неизвестна) циклом и прочитать нужный файл, но как это реализовать на nodejs/js я просто не представляю.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что есть папка имя которой известно, в ней лежит папка с динамическим именем и в этой самой папке лежит файл с известным именем, а цель - прочесть файл?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html. В частности readdir. Ну или воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками типа glob

Comment: @RTK Да, просто прочесть файл.

Comment: Привет твоя проблема актуальная сейчас . Во дворе 2023. А чё твоя ссылка не работает?

Comment: @a.artykaliev удалил :) В целом в решении этой задачи проблем нет, через fs мы смотрим какие есть директории, записываем их в массив, а после уже работаем с ними. То есть, через fs мы смотрим какие вообще существуют директории в нужной директории.